How can I make the logs in WSO2 API Manager more detailed so that I can see who’s connecting and get information about the users who log in?
I’m trying to make the logs in WSO2 API Manager more helpful. I’d like to track who’s connecting and get more details about the users when they log in, such as their usernames and activity information. How can I set that up?
I tried setting up the default logging options in WSO2 API Manager, but I was hoping to get more detailed information. Specifically, I wanted to see not just that someone logged in, but who they were and what they did.

Audit logs are enabled by default. You can check the audit log(audit.log) in <API-M_HOME>/repository/logs directory.
More information can be found here - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/working-with-audit-logs/
